# Exchange ERC20 (Ethereum) with SPL (Solana) via DEX

Tags: ethereum, solana, spl, erc20

I've been searching for a while, but I can't seem to find an answer to this so it would be very helpful if someone can clarify this .

Let's say i have TokenA as an ERC20 deployed to the Ethereum mainnet and I have TokenB as an SPL deployed in the Solana Blockchain.
Is there any way of exchanging those 2 Tokens?

I know with Uniswap I can create my own pool and put some liquidity for my Token, and then swap it with the Selected pair. Eg. TokenA/ETH
But in the case above, the 2 tokens are part of different Blockchains..

Thank you very much

Comment: I have removed the DEX tag from your question because it is for Android DEX code files, not for crypto currency. Please look at the tag descriptions before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The sol wallet will be different from the ERC wallet
You can create smart contract for recieve etherium and one for sol
And by the use of molaris server add watcher for event on the 2 contract when one of them recieve the  token and the recieve wallet for the other blockchain  run script from the molaris server for transfer token for the address from the other blockchain
**Sorry for bad English**

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast.
So that would mean that I would need to create my own DEX, right?
And if i understood correctly, it would look something like:
ContractA -> Receives and Stores TokenA, then triggers an event  and 
ContractB -> Send specified amount of TokenB to specified Address 
and viceversa.

I don't think that's what I'm looking for, but thank you very much. It was pretty helpful.

Comment: If you dont want create your own app you can use https://www.portalbridge.com will create wrapped verison of your token in each blockchain

Comment: Another option to check out to bridge assets between Solana and Ethereum is wormhole: https://wormholenetwork.com/